# How to list all remote repositories in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I'm just looking for a Mercurial command that can list the available repositories in the remote parent repository.  When I used subversion, this was simple, as in:

> svn ls httpx://server/repos/002/trunk
>
> svn ls httpx://server/repos/002/trunk/blort
>
> svn ls httpx://server/repos/002/trunk/blort/fubar

And then I could use ``svn co'' to fetch as much or as little of some directory tree as I wished.

However, I can't find the analog to this in Mercurial.  All the tutorials seem to expect you to know precisely the path to the remote repository and don't discuss anything about even some top level browsing of the remote repository.

Thanks.

Comment: In your example there is also only one repo, `httpx://server/repos`, 002/ and deeper are paths inside of the repository. The difference between SVN and mercurial is that SVN allows to checkout subtrees of a tree, while mercurial always takes the full tree.

Answer (score 8):

There is **only 1 path to the repository**.

With a DVCS you typically clone the repository as a whole. Then you can look at it all you 
want locally.  That is why you have received those answers in the past.

Comment: As an alternative, there are Branches in Mercurial like in git.

Comment: Mercurial has at least 3 ways to handle branching. Best to read up on it. Have you read http://hginit.com/

Comment: But what if you have a repository on the order of several GB in size?  Are you saying that I need to download that whole monster just to get a feel for the top level structure?  I'm just looking for a non-recursive equivalent of ``svn ls'' that works in mercurial.

Comment: Yes.  You always download the entire history of the whole repo with a DVCS -- you always have all history.  If your repo is several GB in size you should stop storing binaries or split it into multiple repositories using subrepos.

Comment: If you really really want to have these giant repos and then browse them, just set up a source browser web app on the machine where your hg repos are, and then you can look at them in your web browser.  "hg serve" will even give you a basic version of this.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about a command but it is doable with a script

```
for repo in `curl $url/hgweb.cgi | \
    grep -v "atom" | \
    grep hgweb.cgi | \
    awk -F'>' '{ print $3}' | \
    awk -F'<' '{print $1}'`; do \
    echo $repo \
    done
```